# Function from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, function, int, hex

I'm looking to convert this exact function from whatever language (Java I think) it is in to C#.

```
String hex_chr = "0123456789abcdef";
private String numToHex(int num) {
    String str = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        str += "" + hex_chr.charAt((num >> (j * 8 + 4)) & 15) + "" + hex_chr.charAt((num >> (j * 8)) & 15);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: It doesn't look like this method is complete - where is hex_chr defined, and what is it defined as? Where are you getting this function from?

Comment: Yes, I attempted to change hex_char.char into hex_char[code here] but that did not work. I also added the definition for hex_chr in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net Framework has a built-in function for that, there's no need to have that ugly, unmaintainable code in your project.

This example leverages a C# feature called [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static string ToHex(this int value)
    {
       return value.ToString("X");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myinteger = 10;
Console.WriteLine(myinteger.ToHex()); //Outputs "A"
```

-- or --

```
Console.WriteLine(255.ToHex()); //Outputs "FF"
```

Comment: While you're right, I'd probably just use `.ToString("X")` directly. Putting an extra call between only hides the parameter, which probably isn't worth it.

Comment: @Alexbeisley agreed, though I still really wanted to use Extensions on this one, just to make the java fanboys cry.

Comment: While I too enjoy using C#, this isn't the place for a language debate.  Your answer would be stronger without the Java deprecation/.Net superiority segment.

Comment: @KenoguLabz I'm not raising a `debate`, there's nothing to debate. I'm exposing technical facts. There's no "debate" on how an airplane is constructed, it's just technical facts. `C# > java on every single aspect` is not something that is subject to anyone's opinion.

Comment: Looking at your answer before the prior edit, it was even more aggressively an attack on Java than it is now.  Again, your answer would be better with just the facts.  The two platforms are both very capable of solving this problem; Java just ends up being more verbose.

Comment: @HighCore, fine, your answer is not the place for a language "rant" then.  Either way, the downvoters are correct that the editorizing is not going to be appreciated.

Comment: @HighCore Know where the appropriate venue for holding a discussion is.  An answer to a question like this is most certainly the wrong venue.  It's _great_ that you can introduce a .Net problem-solving paradigm in the solution, but you can do so without smearing it in Java's face.

Comment: If you want to display it as a full byte, you should .ToString( "X2" )

Answer (score 4):

If you were looking for an exact translation, you just need to deal with it as a char array. You can either use the `ToCharArray()` method or just index into the string directly.

```
String hex_chr = "0123456789abcdef";
private String numToHex(int num)
{
    String str = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        str += "" + hex_chr[(num >> (j * 8 + 4)) & 15] + "" + hex_chr[(num >> (j * 8)) & 15];
    }
    return str;
}
```

You may want to just use the `.ToString("X")` call that HighCore suggested, but keep in mind that this does not include the trailing zeroes present in the string that your code produces.

Likewise, to do that easier in Java the code should have just called `Integer.toHexString()`.